# Помогите ,пожалуйста ,понять в чем ошибка

Tags: python

Боря, Вова и Дима спорят, кто из них выше и в каком порядке они должны стоять в шеренге на уроке физкультуры. Напишите программу, которая упорядочивает рост мальчиков по невозрастанию.

мой код(но пишет ,что неверно):

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
if a > b > c:
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
elif a > c > b:
    print(a)
    print(c)
    print(b)
elif b > a > c:
    print(b)
    print(a)
    print(c)
elif b > c > a:
    print(b)
    print(c)
    print(a)
elif c > a > b:
    print(c)
    print(a)
    print(b)
elif c > b > a:
    print(c)
    print(b)
    print(a)
elif a == b == c:
    print(b)
    print(c)
    print(a)
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [mre]

Comment: А если `a == b != c`?

Comment: @Akina нет, вот вводят три раза 123 и ошибку вообще тогда выдает

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никакой ошибки нет

Возможно подразумевается, что числа вводятся через пробел, типа "1 2 3", тогда нужен код

```
a, b, c = map(int, input().split())
```

Answer (score 1):

Это изначально пример плохого кода, т.к вы вручную перебираете все возможные варианты. Чем этот вариант плох? Тем, что код не будет работать для другого количества учеников. Я бы на вашем месте занёс переменные в список и в нём бы искал порядок расстановки учеников.

Если же вы все таки хотите работать с этим кодом, то, как заметили предыдущие комментаторы, нужен код ошибки и грамотное оформление вопроса. Без них не ясно что происходит, какое поведение программы вы ожидаете и пр.

Answer (score 1):

можно сделать короче:

```
lst = list(map(int, input().split()))
lst.sort()
print(*lst[::-1], sep = '\n')
```

можно в одну строчку:

```
print(*sorted(map(int, input().split()), reverse = True), sep = "\n")
```

Comment: Можно сразу у `sort` указать `reverse=True`, слайс выглядит не так интуитивно понятно

Comment: Во однострочном варианте `list` не нужен, функция `sorted` сама нормально проитерирует результат `map` )